# TypeError: invalid rect assignment. When assigning .rect.center

Tags: python, pygame

As in the title I'm getting "TypeError: invalid rect assignment" On the following line:

`bullet.rect.x=player.rect.center`

Originally the line was:

`bullet.rect.x=player.rect.x`

Which worked fine, aside from the bullet is firing from the left not centre. Not a massive drama as I can manually add +7 to `player.rect.x` but id rather do it in a cleaner way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`player.rect.center` is a tuple and you can't assign a tuple to `bullet.rect.x`. Assign bullet.rect.x to an int or float (which gets truncated) instead.

You can use the **centerx** attribute of the player to set the x of the bullet.rect.

```
bullet.rect.x = player.rect.centerx
```